# Language demographics of Swiss citizens

Tags: data-request, language, demographics, switzerland

I am looking for demographics of languages spoken or not-spoken by Swiss citizens or residents.

Although I don't think it's possible to find this exact dataset, this is the core question: **how many swiss citizens can't speak one of the national languages?**

The best would be on the country level, but broken down into different Cantons. And relevant is if the person speaks or does not speak one of official languages of the country or region.

For example, 95% of Swiss citizens in Kanton Zürich speak German/Swiss-German fluently.

---

I just need some stats, so I'm flexible with the license of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demographics split by official languages, English, and "other" https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/statistiken/bevoelkerung/sprachen-religionen/sprachen.assetdetail.15384580.html

By Kanton: https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/statistiken/bevoelkerung/sprachen-religionen/sprachen.assetdetail.15384656.html.

Part of the population having one of the national languages as (one of) their man language(s):
https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/statistiken/bevoelkerung/migration-integration/integrationindikatoren/alle-indikatoren/sprache/landessprache.assetdetail.5546593.html

By Kanton: https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/statistiken/bevoelkerung/migration-integration/integrationindikatoren/alle-indikatoren/sprache/landessprache.assetdetail.5546605.html

English page: https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/en/home/statistics/population/migration-integration/integration-indicators/all-indicators/language/national-languages-main.html

Percentage of people regularly using 3,2,1 or no national language(s): https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/statistiken/bevoelkerung/migration-integration/integrationindikatoren/alle-indikatoren/sprache/3-2-1-0-landessprachen.assetdetail.5546599.html

English page: https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/en/home/statistics/population/migration-integration/integration-indicators/all-indicators/language/using-national-language.html